# OS error number 13 in a file operation on CentOS?

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, mysql

I am trying to change the data directory on mysql. But getting the following error:

```
121213 04:40:28 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
121213 04:41:00 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /home/mysql_data
121213  4:41:00 [Warning] Can't create test file /home/mysql_data/localhost.lower-test
121213  4:41:00 [Warning] Can't create test file /home/mysql_data/localhost.lower-test
121213  4:41:00  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
121213  4:41:00  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121213  4:41:00  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I have read on many sites its a permission problem. So please tell me how to perform that operations too because I dont know too much about linux.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

errno 13 == Permission denied.

You can see the complete list in `/usr/include/sys/errno.h`<sup>1</sup> .

In your place I would test this by an

```
sudo mysqld -s /bin/bash
```

what starts a shell in the name of the mysql server. Then I would try to change in the directory of the mysql (`/var/lib/mysql`), and if I can't create/remove things there, here is the cause of the problem. Probably you can fix that with some chown/chmod commands (as root).

For example, a `chown mysql:mysql -Rc /var/lib/mysql` makes all files, recursively to the ownership of the user (and group) "mysql", showing the changes for you.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Update from 2019: today it is `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h` on Linuxes.</sub>